# DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA outputs an error during the 'data_src faceset extract' - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

In the [DeepFaceLab](https://github.com/iperov/DeepFaceLab) the 4th and/or 5th process which is extracting the faceset from the data_src and/or data_dst outputs this error:

```
[wf] Face type ( f/wf/head ?:help ) :
wf
[0] Max number of faces from image ( ?:help ) :
0
[512] Image size ( 256-2048 ?:help ) :
512
[90] Jpeg quality ( 1-100 ?:help ) :
90
[n] Write debug images to aligned_debug? ( y/n ) :
n
Extracting faces...

Error while subprocess initialization: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DeepFaceLab\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

On line 64 inside pywrap_tensorflow.py the code and the comments are written like this:

```
  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,line-too-long,undefined-variable
  try:
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.
  # Externally in opensource we must enable exceptions to load the shared object
  # by exposing the PyInit symbols with pybind. This error will only be
  # caught internally or if someone changes the name of the target _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.
```

Similar issues have been [raised in GitHub](https://github.com/iperov/DeepFaceLab/issues) but no concrete answer can be found. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a long time, I finally found the fix. Since I know the training will take a very long time I decided to do this on a laptop that had no GPU. For this very reason, the fix was to do the 10th step first or the cmd file named `10)Make CPU only`. Doing so will uninstall the preinstalled TensorFlow and download an older version so an Internet Connection will be required. Additionally, **executing it cannot be undone**, this means DeepFaceLab will now run through CPU only 4ever unless you reinstall it again.

This should hopefully solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When running
4) data_src faceset extract
I chose CPU at the very beginning of the process (instead of GPU). That worked for me after I faced the same error. Maybe that is more convenient than installing the older Version and not be able to use your GPU anymore.